# getting audio file from attachment and play that file?

Tags: apex, visualforce

This is my code
Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="SOE__c" id="pg" extensions="PlayAudio" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.AudioPlayer, 'audio-player/audio-player.js')}"/>
<script type="text/javascript">  
     AudioPlayer.setup("{!URLFOR($Resource.AudioPlayer, 'audio-player/player.swf')}", {  
         width: 290  
     });  
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">  
    function playAudio(trackObj)
        {
            AudioPlayer.embed("audioplayer_1", {soundFile: trackObj});
        }  
</script>
<apex:form id="frm">
    <apex:pageBlock id="pb">

        <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="count" />
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listAttachment}" var="item" id="pbt">
            <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                {!item.Name}
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="ContentType">
                {!item.ContentType}
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column id="colPlayer" rendered="{!CONTAINS(item.ContentType, 'audio')}">
                <p id="{!count}.audioplayer"></p>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    AudioPlayer.embed("{!count}.audioplayer", {soundFile: 'https://c.na9.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!item.Id}'});
                </script>
                <apex:variable value="{!count+1}" var="count" />
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

class:
//extensions to take care all the lead and activity related attachments and

```
public without sharing class PlayAudio {

    public List<Attachment> listAttachment {get;set;}

    public id SOEid { get; set; }
    public SOE__c SOE {get;set;}
    //constructor
    public PlayAudio(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
       SOEid = Apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
        SOE = (SOE__c)controller.getRecord();

        //initialize the attachments list
        listAttachment = new List<Attachment>();

        //get all the lead related attachments
        listAttachment = [Select Id, ContentType, Name,ParentId from Attachment where ParentId = :SOE.id];

       /* //get all the related tasks attachments
        List<Task> listTask = [Select WhatId from Task where WhoId =: SOE.id ];
        listAttachment.addAll([Select Id, ContentType, Name,ParentId from Attachment where ParentId IN :listTask]);

        //get all the related events attachments
        List<Event> listEvent = [Select WhatId from Event where WhoId =: SOE.id ];
        listAttachment.addAll([Select Id, ContentType, Name from Attachment where ParentId IN :listEvent]);*/

    }
}
```

it is giving error 
       File not found

please help me

Comment: check if you are getting record?

Comment: i am getting the record but unable to play the record

Comment: when i click play button it is showing file not found

Comment: this code is not supported in partner  edition